# Oh My ZSH theme not matching colors

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to make this zsh theme work: https://gist.github.com/3712874

I've made some small changes to it but there is still one problem. It seems that the right triangle glyph doesn't get the same color as the text background. See this image:

[image: ZSH theme]

Any ideas why this might happen, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I switched to iTerm2 to fix this issue in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I made it look pretty good. I had to go change the opacity of my colors. Instead of 100% I had to fiddle a bit and set them around 76-81% depending on what color it was.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

On Linux using Terminal I had to change the Profile Preferences->Colors. For example, I wanted to use the theme [dpoggi](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes#dpoggi). I downloaded the theme image, then used the dropper tool to match the "red" "green", "cyan", and "magenta" that are used in the [dpoggi source code](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/dpoggi.zsh-theme).

**dpoggi theme**

[image: dpoggi theme]

**Terminal Profile Preferences->Colors**
[image: Linux Profile Preferences Colors]

Answer (score 0):

I found that playing with the "Cursor guide" transparency in Preferences > Profiles worked for me. It can also be disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: iterm]

Make sure Minimum Contrast setting in your iterm is set to 0. If the contrast is increased all colores will skew towards black or white.

Answer (score 0):

When enabling transparency, make sure you check "Keep background colors opaque" box:
[image]